# Approximation algorithm for sine function

Tags: approximation

What is the most common approximation algorithm for sine function which can be implemented with [self-organizing maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-organizing_map) algorithm? I was thinking of least-squares approximation but I can't find a description of it for sine(or any trigonometrical) function.

Comment: Are you looking at real or complex arguments? $\sin x, x \in \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: john, only real

Comment: Can you just sample the sine function at evenly space points and get something piecewise-linear?  Then your SOM has to approach this collection of lines.